# rename columns names while reading duplicate column names from xls

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to import an xls file from readxl package with duplicate column
 names "Class A. a1",   "Class A. a1",  "Section B. b1", "Section B.
 b1","Class B.","Class B." from it.

After reading it as R dataframe the colnames shows as follows "Class A. a1", "Class A. a1__1" ,"Section B. b1" , "Section B. b1__1", "Class B." ,"Class B.__1"

Now I am replacing the "__" with "-" as below

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("sample.xls",col_names = TRUE) 
names(df) <- gsub(x = names(df), pattern = "__", replacement = "-")
```

Is there any way to replace identical columns from "__" to "-" while reading itself ,instead of after reading the file.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data. Use `dput(head(df))` or simply the output of `names(df))`

Comment: No, the function doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a file called `Book1.xlsx` with 3 numeric columns, called A, B and B.

```
library(read_xl)

read_xlsx("Book1.xlsx", col_names = c("A", "B", "C"), skip = 1)
```

`skip = 1` prevents it from reading the original names which are A, B, and B

Answer (score 0):

`read_excel()` function of `readxl` package doesn't have that option.

To check what are the arguments the `read_excel` function accepts type `?readxl::read_excel()`  in the console or in editor then run it.

It will open the documentation of that function.